# Truncated ScrollViewer contains TextBlock

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have found strange behaviour with ScrollViewer contains TextBlock.
Just I enter more than 48 strings the text is displayed truncated while sliding.

Here is my example:

```
<controls:PivotItem x:Name="PivotItem2" Header="2">
                       <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="427">
                        <StackPanel  Margin="0,0,0,6">
                          <StackPanel.Background>
                             <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
                           </StackPanel.Background>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="DATE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PublicDate" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="CONTENT" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White"  FontSize="32">
                             <Run Text="1"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="2"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="3"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="4"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="5"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="6"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="7"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="8"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="9"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="0"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="11"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="12"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="13"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="14"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="15"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="16"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="17"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="18"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="19"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="20"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="21"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="22"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="23"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="24"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="25"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="26"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="27"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="28"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="29"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="30"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="31"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="32"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="33"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="34"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="35"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="36"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="37"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="38"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="39"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="40"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="41"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="42"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="43"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="44"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="45"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="46"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="47"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="48"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="49"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="50"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="51"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="52"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="53"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="54"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="55"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="56"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="57"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="58"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="59"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="60"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="61"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="62"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="63"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="64"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="65"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="66"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="67"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="68"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="69"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="70"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="71"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="72"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="73"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="74"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="75"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="76"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="77"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="78"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="79"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="80"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="81"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="82"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="83"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="84"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="85"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="86"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="87"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="88"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="!Binding MessageText"/>
             </TextBlock>

                     </StackPanel>
                      </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid> 
   </controls:PivotItem>
```

Here is my screenshoot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is standard scrollviewer behaviour (even outside of silverlight). The content scrolls to where ever the user stops. You need to implement additional logic if you want the text items to be always in view when the user stops scrolling.

Comment: Can you give an example of necessary code to implement this logic?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never had to implement this but the general idea would be to to hook into the some events in the scrollviewer and then change the offset value when the user stops scrolling. Without actually doing this myself I can't help.